# Python selenium поиск по последним символам

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Помогите пожалуста, как-то можно найти id в selenium  по последним симвалам, я знаю что на сайте эсть кнопка в котором id=q5104854:1_answer0 но q5104854 постояно меняеться по этому нужно найти id по 1_answer0 и нажать на кнопку

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76585379/how-to-construct-locators-for-dynamic-elements-using-selenium-and-python